# converting date functions from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I am coverting a time differnce function I made over a year ago in javascript to a php function. Most of it is pretty similar but there's one part I just cant figure out. the `setMonth()` function is kind of similar to `$date->modify`, but the values are returned in different formats and it's confusing me. If any one can find a php equivelent to the following javascript I would be most grateful. Thanks.

```
 var date1 = new Date();
 var date2 = date('some date');

 var dayDiff = date1.setMonth(date1.getMonth() + month);   
 var  day = Math.abs(Math.floor((date2.getTime() - dayDiff) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
```

Comment: instead of giving us the JS tell us what you want to do

Comment: Plus the fact that it's simply a bad code in JS.
dayDiff isn't the day difference, it's the current date month + an amount of months added...
As @Dagon said, you better know what you really want, don't try to port things that seem badly coded.
Is it a function that returns the number of days difference between the {currentDate} and the {currentDate + n * months}?

Comment: this part ofthe function is to determine the amount of days after a month as there are different numbers of days in month eg. 32 days could be a month and one day in January or it could be a month and 4 days in February. the varable names are bit confusing. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official website of php:
http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.diff.php

### Add your months using -> modify

$currentDate -> modify('+' . $months . ' month');

### Get the date difference using -> diff

$interval = $currentDate -> diff($otherDate, true);

The second boolean parameter indicates that you do not care about negative differences, output will always be positive (as your Math.abs did in the javascript version).

### And output it with -> format

$interval->format('%R%a days')

---

### Full example

```
// If you need to set the timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// Whatever month you want to add to $currentDate
$months = 2; // months has to be an int

$currentDate = new DateTime();
$otherDate   = new DateTime('2014-01-04');

$currentDate -> modify('+' . $months . ' month');

$interval = $currentDate -> diff($otherDate, true);

echo($interval->format('%R%a days'));
```